# Sending data mssql server to MySQL using Kafka connect

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to deploy [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) in [kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes). I have following questions:

1. Do I need to create MS SQL Server db tables in MySQL database? Or Kafka connect will create?
2. Any reference how to implement Kafka Connect without Avro Schema registry?
3. How to give configurations of key and value convertors?

Comment: > MS SQL Server db tables in MySQL database - What do you mean?